# Why isn't the angular google-map component recognized by angular even though its module has been added to the app module?

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps

I have added the google maps module to my app.module.ts but it keeps giving me an error.

I suspected the issue might be from the version of the packages I installed. I updated angular to angular 15 (latest now), and updated all the packages I had installed. I run npm cache verify to ensure that it was not a caching problem. I restarted the angular server several times, but I still kept getting the error NG8001: 'google-map' is not a known element.

Error: app/components/home/home.component.html:3:3 - error NG8001: 'google-map' is not a known element:

1. If 'google-map' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'google-map' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
   3

src/app/components/home/home.component.ts:13:16
13   templateUrl: './home.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component HomeComponent.
app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatLegacySnackBarModule as MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-snack-bar';
import { MatLegacyDialogModule as MatDialogModule, MAT_LEGACY_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS as MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material/legacy-dialog';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { ChooseDestinationComponent } from './components/choose-destination/choose-destination.component';
import { GooglePlaceModule } from 'ngx-google-places-autocomplete';
import { AwaitingComponent } from './components/awaiting/awaiting.component';
import { DiverHomeComponent } from './components/driver-components/diver-home/diver-home.component';
import { OngoingRideComponent } from './components/ongoing-ride/ongoing-ride.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ConfirmDialogComponent } from './components/dialogs/confirm-dialog/confirm-dialog.component';
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { provideAnalytics, getAnalytics, ScreenTrackingService, UserTrackingService } from '@angular/fire/analytics';
import { provideAuth, getAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { provideDatabase, getDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';
import { DatabaseService } from './services/database.service';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { CallNumber } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/call-number/ngx';
import { StartTripComponent } from './components/dialogs/start-trip/start-trip.component';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
import { DriverCardComponent } from './components/driver-card/driver-card.component';
import { SignUpComponent } from './components/sign-up/sign-up.component';
import { SignInComponent } from './components/sign-in/sign-in.component';
import { AuthGuardService } from './services/auth-guard.service';
import { GoogleMapsModule } from '@angular/google-maps';


@NgModule({
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ChooseDestinationComponent,
    AwaitingComponent,
    DiverHomeComponent,
    OngoingRideComponent,
    ConfirmDialogComponent,
    StartTripComponent,
    DriverCardComponent,
    SignUpComponent,
    SignInComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    GoogleMapsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    HttpClientModule,
    GooglePlaceModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAnalytics(() => getAnalytics()),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideDatabase(() => getDatabase()),
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: { hasBackdrop: false } },
    ScreenTrackingService,
    UserTrackingService,
    AngularFireDatabase,
    DatabaseService,
    AuthService,
    CallNumber,
    AuthGuardService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


package.json
{
  "name": "lorley",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.1.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.1.4",
    "@angular/common": "^15.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.1.4",
    "@angular/core": "^15.1.4",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.5.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.1.4",
    "@angular/google-maps": "^15.1.4",
    "@angular/material": "^15.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.1.4",
    "@angular/router": "^15.1.4",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/call-number": "^5.46.0",
    "@capacitor-community/capacitor-googlemaps-native": "^1.2.0",
    "@capacitor/android": "^4.0.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "^4.6.1",
    "@capacitor/geolocation": "^4.0.1",
    "@capacitor/google-maps": "^4.0.1",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^4.0.1",
    "@capacitor/preferences": "^4.0.2",
    "call-number": "^1.0.1",
    "ngx-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.0.5",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.1.5",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.1.4",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^4.6.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally noticed the problem. The component I was using was not part of the declarations array of app.module.ts. For that reason, it appears the component was not running as part of the module. Hence, it was not seeing the GoogleMapsModule. This is what I believed happened.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you didn't installed type declarations for google maps.

Use the below code to install it.

```
npm i @types/google.maps
```

Comment: + probably edit the `tsconfig.app.json` by adding `"googlemaps"` to the `compilerOptions:types`

Comment: I tried both suggestions but I still get the same error